# SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure / alert number 40

Tags: ssl, certificate

Using OpenSSL 1.0.2p on MacOS

```
openssl s_client -connect XXX.XXX.com:443 -CAfile server.pem -debug
```

Results in

```
140735528117192:error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.50.2/libressl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1133:SSL alert number 40
140735528117192:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.50.2/libressl/ssl/s23_lib.c:124
```

Using  gnutls-cli -d 0 -V XXX.XXX.com:443

```
- Status: The certificate is trusted.
- Server's trusted authorities:
   [0]: DELETED
- Successfully sent 0 certificate(s) to server.
*** Fatal error: A TLS fatal alert has been received.
*** Received alert [40]: Handshake failed
*** handshake has failed: A TLS fatal alert has been received.
```

Thank you!

Comment: Enforce TLS connection, remote site doesn't support SSL2/3